# Kubernetes pod throwing CredentialUnavailableException: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-web-app-service, azure-aks

I am running a Spring Boot application utilizing Azure Kubernetes Service. I found this strange error in my pod logs recently.

> com.azure.identity.CredentialUnavailableException: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
> ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Connection to IMDS endpoint cannot be established.
> SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.
> IntelliJ Authentication not available. Please log in with Azure Tools for IntelliJ plugin in the IDE.
> Failed to read Vs Code credentials from Linux Key Ring.
> AzureCliCredential authentication unavailable. Azure CLI not installed.To mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azsdk/java/identity/azclicredential/troubleshoot
> Unable to execute PowerShell. Please make sure that it is installed in your systemTo mitigate this issue, please refer to the troubleshooting guidelines here at https://aka.ms/azure-identity-java-default-azure-credential-troubleshoot

Any hints are much appreciated !

My trails so far:

1. Upgrade/Downgrade Kubernetes versions
2. Checking Environment Variable Assignments

Answer (score 1):

**Could you please validate that you are setting the following environment variables?**

1. **ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES**
   ensure that the variables **azure_client, azure_tenant and azure_client_secret** are properly set.

Below steps will work when authenticate using **environment variables**:
Please add the following variables in env_path,

```
export AZURE_CLIENT_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
export AZURE_TENANT_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
export AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET=XXXXXXXX
```

Check your environment variables with

```
System.getenv("AZURE_CLIENT_ID")
```

2. **MANAGEDIDENTITY_CREDENTIALS**

Managed Identity is currently unsupported by the Java, we can use an ***secret*** or a ***certificate*** authentication
for Sample:

```
export AZURE_CLIENT_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
export AZURE_TENANT_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
export AZURE_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_PATH=XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

3. In **VS**,  go to *Tools* > *Options*>*Azure Service Authentication* > *Account Selection*> *Sign_in* with your credentials

[image]

If you see the "*Re-enter your credentials* link, click it and sign in again.
if not  *sign_out* and *sign_in* again.

4. **PROFILE_ENV_APPLICATION**
   Please check the profile environment for the application

`windir\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config`

In *application.config* file if  it *setProfileEnvironment* is ***false***, change it to ***True***.

If not, add it under <*applicationPoolDefaults*> tag  like below.

```
<applicationPoolDefaults managedRuntimeVersion="vXX">
<processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true">
```

5. **SHARED_TOKEN_CASHE_CREDENTIAL**

for shared token cache credentials we have to add the below command

```
DefaultAzureCredential(connection_verify=False, exclude_shared_token_cache_credential=True
```

6. **AZURE_CLI_CREDENTIAL** AND  **AZURE_CLI**
   in ***environment variable*** add your *PATH*
   run the terminal
   echo $PATH
7. **POWERSHELL**

open the PowerShell and run as a administrator,
run the command to fix the disk and display a status report

```
Chkdsk c: /F
```

after this command You will have to restart the computer to work the PowerShell.